# Are autovacuum VACUUMs slower than a manual VACUUM?

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum

I have a few large tables that take *days* to autovacuum, sometimes resulting in poor performance until the vacuum finishes.  Most of the recommendations I've seen mention doing a manual `VACUUM` during off-hours so that the autovacuum `VACUUM`s have less work to do, but if autovacuum takes days to finish is there any way to squeeze a manual `VACUUM` in (given a 24-hour peak activity cycle)?

I assume a manual `VACUUM` would still take days to finish?  Or is my assumption incorrect?

---

Related: [Do the different "types" of autovacuum have different performance characteristics?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161635/do-the-different-types-of-autovacuum-have-different-performance-characteristic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Sort-of".

Automatic `VACUUM` may run at a lower intensity than manual vacuum, so it pauses longer between each batch. `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` may be set differently to `vacuum_cost_delay`; by default there is no delay on manual vacuum, only on autovacuum.

Autovacuum also works harder to avoid blocking concurrent queries and will abort its work if another query tries to take a lock that would conflict with vacuum. Depending on the vacuum phase this may not actually slow it down much, or it might throw away substantial work. The first phase heap sweep marking dead tuples and setting the visibility map doesn't care much if it's aborted part-way, though it might cause a subsequent vacuum to repeat some of the reads. It's much more expensive when we're updating indexes, but that's done in batches to reduce the amount of work lost if a vacuum is canceled.

See [autovacuum configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html) for the relevant parameters, most notably `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay`. Note that this differs from [the `vacuum_cost_delay` setting used by manual vacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html).